# How can I split the integer stream into buffers using conditional windows instead of time based windows?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, observable, unirx

I have an Observable that returns integers like so:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0
```

How can I convert this Observable to return arrays of those integers splitting stream not by the time based windows but by value based ones?

Those integers are fingerId of Touch in Unity Update event. It's not so important for this task but to explain why I need it I have to provide these details. -1 is for no touch. This is the gap. I need to remove those -1 parts and split stream to buffers of fingerId's between «no touch» moments. I can describe this like this too:

```
Touch0, Touch0, Touch0, no Touch, no Touch, Touch1
```

It doesnt' matter if there is integer or another type. Just need to split stream into buffers removing «window values».

This is my code if it will be helpful:

```
var leftSideTouchStream = Observable.EveryUpdate()
            .Scan(-1, (id, _) =>
            {
                if (id < 0)
                {
                    var leftSideTouches = Input.touches
                        .Where(t =>
                            t.phase == TouchPhase.Began
                            && t.position.x < Screen.width / 2
                        );

                    return leftSideTouches.Any() ? leftSideTouches.First().fingerId : -1;

                }
                else
                {
                    var touchEnded = Input.touches
                        .Any(t =>
                            t.fingerId == id &&
                            (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || t.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
                        );

                    return touchEnded ? -1 : id;
                }
            })
            .Select(id =>
            {
                return Input.touches
                    .Where(t => t.fingerId == id)
                    .Select(t => new Nullable<Touch>(t))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            });
```

I need exactly the same behaviour as Buffer function gives but as I said according to values not the time.
If I have this stream:

```
1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0
```

And the «window value» is -1, then the result is expected to be:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't find any out-of-the-box solution so I came up with my own Observable implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UniRx;

public static class ObservableFunctions
{
    public static IObservable<T[]> BufferWhen<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T[]>(observer =>
        {
            List<T> buffer = new List<T>();

            source.Subscribe(
                t =>
                {
                    if (predicate(t))
                    {
                        buffer.Add(t);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (buffer.Count > 0)
                        {
                            observer.OnNext(buffer.ToArray());
                            buffer = new List<T>();
                        }
                    }
                },
                e =>
                {
                    observer.OnError(e);
                },
                () =>
                {
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
            );

            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    }
}
```

Luckily it was very simple. Simplier than searching for the appropriate function in Google...

Answer (score 0):

There might exist some better magic solutions but the most straight forward I guess would be somthing like

```
private static int[][] GetArrays(int[] intputArray)
{
    // use lists for dynamically adding elements
    var outputLists = new List<List<int>>();

    // initialize with the ignored value
    var lastValue = -1;

    // iterate over the inputArray
    foreach (var value in intputArray)
    {
        // skip -1 values
        if (value < 0)
        {
            lastValue = -1;
            continue;
        }

        // if a new value begin a new list
        if (lastValue != value)
        {
            outputLists.Add(new List<int>());
        }

        // add the value to the current (= last) list
        outputLists[outputLists.Count - 1].Add(value);

        // update the lastValue
        lastValue = value;
    }

    // convert to arrays
    // you could as well directly return the List<List<int>> instead
    // and access the values exactly the same way
    // but since you speak of buffers I guess you wanted arrays explicitely
    var outputArrays = new int[outputLists.Count][];
    for (var i = 0; i < outputLists.Count; i++)
    {
        outputArrays[i] = outputLists[i].ToArray();
    }

    return outputArrays;
}
```

so calling

```
var arrays = GetArrays(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0});
```

should result in

```
arrays[0] => [1, 1, 1, 1]
arrays[1] => [0, 0, 0, 0]
arrays[2] => [0, 0, 0]
```

---

since you seem to rather want to add values one by one dynamically I wouldn't use arrays at all but instead use something like

```
private List<List<int>> arrays = new List<List<int>>();

private int lastValue;

private void AddValue(int value)
{
    // skip -1 values
    if (value < 0)
    {
        lastValue = -1;
        return;
    }

    // if a new value begin a new list
    if (lastValue != value)
    {
        arrays.Add(new List<int>());
    }

    // add the value to the current (= last) list
    arrays[outputLists.Count - 1].Add(value);

    // update the lastValue
    lastValue = value;
}
```

I mean something you have to store somewhere

Comment: Sorry, but it's not the case. Your solution is bound to Enumerable logic. But my question is about Observables. Thank you anyway.

Comment: well an observable returns one single value every time ... I guess somewhere you are storing those? Maybe you could add your code for the `Observable` then

Comment: You're right, of course I can grab them manually and insert them into lists but doing so makes no sense for using Observables. I can achieve my goal just writing ordinary imperative code that I'm used to. But I want to do it using reactive approach. First of all to learn it and second to make my code maintainable in future.

Comment: well I don't see how you want to archive storing values into arrays if you don't implement any way of storing the latest values somwhere ... I mean you could also skip the inputArray and rather diectly use the codeblock from the `foreach`

Comment: As I wrote in my question Buffer function does nearly all I need. Except it uses time gaps not «value gaps» between the values. It stores all the values in Observale itself as much as I know.

Comment: well this depends a lot on the implementation of your `Observable` ... and the according `Buffer` method